# How to cancel a booking for a specific row using php and mysql

Tags: php

I have a table with each row having a cancel link. I would like to cancel a booking for the specific rows. May I know how to start?
The codes of the table is as below.

```
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo "<table border = 1>
        <tr>
              <th>Custid</th>
              <th>Venue</th>
              <th>Firt Name</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Time</th>
              <th>Menu Type </th>
              <th>No.of table </th>
              <th>Total price </th>
              <th>Amount Paid </th>
              <th>Make Payment </th>
              <th>Cancel Booking</th>
        </tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
              echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td>" . $row['Customer_id']. " </td>";
                   echo "<td>" . $row['Venue_name']. " </td>";
                   echo "<td>" . $row['First_name'].  "</td>";
                   echo "<td>" . $row['Date']. "</td>";
                   echo "<td>" . $row['Time']. "</td>";
                   echo "<td>" . $row['Menu_type']. "</td>";
                   echo "<td>" . $row['no_of_table']. "</td>";
                   echo "<td>" . $row['total_price']. "</td>";
                   echo "<td>" . $row['total_amt_paid']. "</td>";
                   echo"<td><a href='Payment.php'>Payment</a></td>";
                   echo"<td><a href='Cancel.php'>Cancel</a></td>";
              echo "</tr>";
        }

      echo "</table>";                              

   }
```

Comment: you can add to cancel.php call the id with url querystring maybe.

Comment: `href="cancel.php?$row[id]"` or whatever...

Comment: For both the `Payment` and `Cancel` you need at least an `ID` to identify your row.

Comment: Cancel.php would have an `UPDATE` query, flipping a field named 'status' from 0 (open) to 1 (cancelled).

Comment: hi I have added echo "<td><a href='Cancel.php?id=" .$row['booking_id']. "'>Cancel</a></td>";

Comment: may I know how to write the selected code for deleted each specific row

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `Cancel.php` script some knowledge of what it should delete, so change

```
echo "<td><a href='Cancel.php'>Cancel</a></td>";
```

to

```
echo '<td><a href="Cancel.php?Customer_id=' . $row['Customer_id'] . '">Payment</a></td>';
```

And then in the `Cancel.php` script you should receive that value in the $_GET array

```
<?php

    $Customer_id = $_GET['Customer_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel a specific booking you'll need something specific about each booking, like a booking id for example. If we assume you already have that in your table then you can pass this unique value (specific to the row) to your cancel.php and payment.php pages.

To do this we will use a get request and a query string. This will mean your original line changes from this:

```
echo "<td><a href='Cancel.php'>Cancel</a></td>";
```

to this one below. We can add the query string unique to each row like this: (assuming it might be called `booking_id`)

```
echo "<td><a href='Cancel.php?booking_id=".$row['booking_id']."'>Cancel</a></td>";
```

You can now retrieve this value on the Cancel.php page like this:

```
$booking_id = $_GET['booking_id'];
```

It's worth reading up about [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) and consider adding some cleaning method for your string to avoid this. If you are a little rusty on GET and POST then you can check [this explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) out.

Comment: Hi andy, yes I am using booking_id for deletion. Is it I retrieve the value of $booking_id = $_GET['booking_id']; and can delete this value selected?

Comment: `$_GET['booking_id']` holds the value passed via Cancel.php?booking_id. So if you follow a link like this: `Cancel.php?booking_id=2` then `$_GET['booking_id']` will be 2. In order to delete you'll need to use a query that will delete WHERE booking_id is equal to `$booking_id`

Comment: is $booking_id = $_GET['booking_id']; global? so sorry Im a bit new to php. Do I put this in Cancel.php page?

Comment: how to store $booking_id and bring over to cancel.php page?

Comment: If you visit cancel.php?booking_id=2 then on the cancel.php page when you look at the value of $_GET['booking_id'] it will also be 2. That is how you 'bring it over' to cancel.php. If you're having trouble with this I suggest you visit this page: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp as I suggested in my answer :)

Comment: $sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM booking WHERE booking_id = '$booking_id'"; this statement is not working but when I put $sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM booking WHERE booking_id =1"; it is fine. may I know what went wrong